# firefox extension crashes for none reason

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have one extension for firefox done, no erros on the code, everything is working, but for some reason sometimes stop working and make firefox crash. I made a lot of testes and different cases.
My question is, how can I debug this extension?
There's some way quicker to install the extension then everytime I make some change I need to compress to zip, uninstall and reinstall again the extension.

I'm using Firefox 25.0 on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: a javascript that find all words that match with an array, and when my cursor is hover that word show a frame with some information.

Comment: Sorry it should have stated this in my first comment. But could you provide us with some code? How more information how better.

Comment: You don't have to zip uninstall and install with every change, just place uncompressed folder with your extension if <User>\AppData\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<Profile>\Extesions\<YourExtension> and just restart firefox when you made some changes

Comment: and in ubuntu? where should i place the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Open `about:crashes` page in Firefox there will be a lot of info about your Firefox crashes(if it really crashes). If this is just JavaScript errors, try using Firebug or JavaScript console to get more info